# How to use html-pdf-node in typescript

Tags: typescript, pdf

I need to use this package in node, i'm using typescript.

The example code in the doc, show this:

```
    var html_to_pdf = require('html-pdf-node');

let options = { format: 'A4' };
// Example of options with args //
// let options = { format: 'A4', args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] };

let file = { content: "<h1>Welcome to html-pdf-node</h1>" };
// or //
let file = { url: "https://example.com" };
html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options).then(pdfBuffer => {
  console.log("PDF Buffer:-", pdfBuffer);
});
```

but, how i can using this, in typescript context?

Comment: Can you tell us about your project structure like tsconfig.json file location, src.index.ts, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library doesn't support typescript and there is no `@types/html-pdf-node` package, so you must create the so-called declaration file yourself.

The declaration file should be named something like `html-pdf-node.d.ts` and its content should start with:

```
declare module "html-pdf-node"{
}
```

Now inside the module you declare the functions the library exports, let's take your generatePdf function and see how to declare it, first it's obvious it takes two parameters and returns a promise, so we start with this:

```
declare module "html-pdf-node"{
    export function generatePdf(file: IFile,options: IOptions) => Promise<Buffer>;
}
```

So `generatePdf` takes two parameters, first is of type `IFile` which we're going to define in the same module above later, the same goes for `IOptions`, the function returns `Promise<Buffer>` where `Buffer` is NodeJS's `Buffer`.

Now to define IFile interface like this:

```
declare module "html-pdf-node"{
   interface IFile{
       content: string;
   }
   export function generatePdf(file: IFile,options: IOptions) => Promise<Buffer>;
}
```

You define `IOptions` in the same way and Voilà! Your library is now type safe, the file `html-pdf-node.d.ts` should be put in a `@types` folder in the root project directory.

But wait, `IFile` supports options other than just `content`?!! Well you only define what you need to use not everything the library supports, so you need to use other options? Just change `IFile`, did a new version of the library change `generatePdf` to take three parameters and not accept two? Just change its type in `html-pdf-node.d.ts`.

Anyway I've put all this for you to learn how to deal with a mandatory library that doesn't have any typings defined in the community, the better approach for your case is to switch to another library that is maintained and maybe has typescript built-in or at least `@types/some-library` package.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the tsconfig.json

[structure project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEe6n.jpg)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2021",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "rootDirs": ["./src", "./tests"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/@types"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@configurations/*": ["./src/configurations/*"],
      "@controllers/*": ["./src/controllers/*"],
      "@entities/*": ["./src/entities/*"],
      "@helpers/*": ["./src/helpers/*"],
      "@repositories/*": ["./src/repositories/*"],
      "@services/*": ["./src/services/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["./src/utils/*"]
    }
  },
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "include": [
      "jest"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src",
    "tests"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "lib",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: you should edit your question not put it as an answer, this is a Q/A website not a forum

Comment: Leave more information on what has changed, if there's already an answer it's better to update question